# ¿Como evitar que aparezca una ventana no planificada?

Tags: python, botón, programación-funcional, ventana, funcion

estoy tratando de asignarle a un mismo botón para que al presionarlo cierre la ventana principal (Tk) que es la ventana del login name y que aparezca una segunda ventana (Toplevel) y esta permanezca como panel principal. inicialmente funciona, pero al aparecer la ventana Toplevel y desaparecer la ventana del login name, conjuntamente aparece una pequeña ventana que no he logrado ni advertir como aparece ni he podido solucionar... Aquí está el código de las 2 funciones y el botón, si se requiere el código completo hacédmelo saber...

```
def login_window_destroy():
    root.destroy()

def principal_panel():
    ventana2 = Toplevel()
    ventana2.geometry(“1200x600”)
    ventana2.title(“PANEL PRINCIPAL”)

triple_button=Button(root,text='INGRESAR',activebackground="#00B0F0",activeforeground="white",fg='gray',bg="#F0F8FF",font=("Arial",12,'bold'),command= lambda:
```

[login_window_destroy(),principal_panel()]).place(x=290,y=310,width=160)

root.mainloop()

Comment: Los toplevel no pueden existir sin una ventana raiz (Tk). Cuando inicias un toplevel sin passr ningun argumento, automaticamente crea una ventana raiz en la que el toplevel se creará.

Comment: Solución: no uses toplevels, usa Tks.

Comment: Muchas gracias Dante, solucionado....

Comment: De nada Old bit-RD c:

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque en los comentarios se dio la solución.